# find the limit by taking an arbitrary constant

Tags: calculus, limits

It's a little bit confusing but can someone give me some hints about the solution of this limit? 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-b^x}{\tan x}
$$
I tried logging both sides of a function related but yet I didn't manage to achieve something understandable.

Comment: What is $t,g$? Are they constants?

Comment: I assume it's a notation for $\tan$.

Comment: sorry it is tanx

Comment: Is really the limit $x\to a$? Or is it $x\to 0$?

Comment: Yeah, because lim $x->a$ can be found out just by plugging in $x=a$

Comment: yes, why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: What doesn't make sense?

Comment: i fixed it, what about now

Comment: Do you know about L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: yes, a little bit

Comment: Try applying it. It gives you the answer in one step.

Comment: No real need for L'Hopital -- there are simpler, less "hammer-like" ways to deal with this sort of limits at 0 (ratio of two functions that have simple Taylor expansions).

Comment: ok, can you give a hint

Comment: @ClementC. What exactly do you mean by L'Hopitals' being "hammer-like"?

Comment: Well, it's quite a big, non-trivial theorem (also, as a matter of taste, i just don't like it).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the limit you are trying to compute is $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-b^x}{\tan x}$, for fixed $0< a,b$ with $a\neq b$.

Writing the Taylor expansion to degree 1, when $x\to 0$ we have
$$
\frac{a^x-b^x}{\tan x} = \frac{e^{x\ln a} - e^{x\ln b}}{x+o(x)} =  \frac{x\ln a - x\ln b + o(x)}{x+o(x)} = \ln a - \ln b + o(1)
$$
where we used the fact that $e^x  = 1+x + o(x)$ and $\tan x = x + o(x)$ when $x\to 0$. Thus, the overall limit is 
$$\lim_{\substack{x\to 0\\x\neq 0}} \frac{a^x-b^x}{\tan x} = \ln \frac{a}{b}.$$

Comment: it's a bit complicated can you do it only by l'hopital

Comment: You can. I won't. (as stated in a comment above, I for once do not like this theorem and its pervasive use that much; and the above also gives you some training in dealing with simple Taylor expansions, which are at least as ubiquitous as L'Hopital's rule in everyday research).

Comment: ok thanks clement

Answer (score 3):

Transform this into
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{a^x-1}{x}-\frac{b^x-1}{x}\right)\frac{x}{\tan x}
$$
In the parentheses you find the definition of derivative of $f(x)=a^x$ at $0$; the part outside the parentheses should be easy.

Or, if you want to use l’Hôpital, recall that the derivative of $f(x)=a^x$ is $f'(x)=a^x\log a$ and that the derivative of $g(x)=\tan x$ is $g'(x)=1+\tan^2x$
so you get

> $\lim\limits_{x\to0}{a^x-b^x}{\tan x}\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{a^x\log a-b^x\log b}{1+\tan^2x}$